# Legendary Annoyance of IE6's margin and padding "behaviour" (Help!)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, padding, margin

Everything is OK in Chrome, FF and IE8. But in IE6 there's a strange margin right below the **div "middle-column"** (inside it there are 3 **divs called featured1, 2 and 3.**) which is above **the divs "left-column"** and **"right-column"**). I already tried everything to get rid of that problem. I tried the "display: inline technique" and CSS resets. Please Help! I'm testing my website [here](http://weedcl.sqweebs.com/)

MY HTML:

```
<body id="home">
<!-- header -->
<div id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <h1><a href="http://widerdesign.co.nr/">wider design</a></h1>
        <!-- navigation -->
        <ul id="navigation"> 
            <li class="home"><a href="index.php"><span>home</span></a></li>
            <li class="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.php"><span>portfolio</span></a></li>
            <li class="about"><a href="about.php"><span>about</span></a></li>
            <li class="contact"><a href="contact.php"><span>contact</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="top-column">
        <p>We <strong>design and develop</strong> clean and effective webs in the <strong>top 3 languages</strong> 
        on the Internet. Internet is mean to reach the whole world.You are mean to reach the whole audience:</p> 
    </div>
    <div id="middle-column">
        <h2>Featured Projects</h2>
        <div id="featured1">
            <a href="contact.php" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="images/project1.png"/></a>
            <p>Featured work number 1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="featured2">
            <a href="contact.php" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="images/project2.png"/></a>
            <p>Featured work number 2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="featured3">
            <a href="contact.php" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="images/project3.png"/></a>
            <p>Featured work number 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="left-column">
            <h2>Web Design</h2>
            <p>Create a web site easily with this online HTML generator. Follow the steps below to create web pages then click "view html page" to test it once it's completed. You can copy and paste generated code where you wish within the generated document(s). For example: You created an HTML table with 3 rows and 3 columns. You then added a link, which appears below the HTML table. If you want the link inside the HTML table, just cut and paste it inside the table in place of an "ADD TEXT" statement. Any where text,images,or links need to be, there will be a generated "ADD TEXT" statement in the HTML pages.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="right-column">
            <h2>Web Translation</h2>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    try {
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-11932489-1");
    pageTracker._trackPageview();
    } catch(err) {}
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

MY CSS Reset:

```
/* reset */
* { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

img {
    border: none;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}
/* tags */
body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #757575;
    font-family: Arial, "MS Trebuchet", sans-serif;
    font-size: 75%;
}
h1 {
    background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
h2 {
    color: #669BD9;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
a {
    font-family: Arial, "MS Trebuchet", sans-serif;
}
/* classes */
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}
```

My CSS Structure:

```
#content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}

#content h2 {
    border-top: 1px dashed #C0C0C0;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #C0C0C0;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 0;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

#top-column {
    color: #818181;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial, "MS Trebuchet", sans-serif;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    padding: 10px 0 20px 0;
}

#top-column strong {
    font-weight: normal; 
    color: #3C3C3C;
}

#middle-column div {
    float: left;
    height: 224px;
    width: 320px;
}

#right-column {
    float: left;
    width: 420px;
}
#left-column {
    float: right;
    width: 500px;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I just realized that IE adds some margin (or padding) for each #featured div inside #middle-column. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at `div id="slideshow"`, you'll see that it has `margin:10px auto` which is basically saying to apply a margin-top of 10px and a margin-bottom of 10px. IE6 tends to double margins so by applying `margin:5px 0;` it should display the same as it does in Firefox, IE8, IE7 and all other up to date browsers.

-- Also just for reference, the 'auto' style was not needed in this case, this is generally used if you are looking to make an element sit in the center of its parent. An example of this would be if you wanted a website to display in the center of your screen you would use `'margin:0 auto;'`

I hope this solves your problem!